# View json log file content in colums with php

Tags: php, json

I have a log file, which is created by php json.

This part is creating the log file:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Budapest');
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTimeStamp = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data = array("datetime" => $dateTimeStamp ); 
$data += $_REQUEST;
$req_dump = json_encode( $data ) . "\n";
$fp = file_put_contents( 'data.log', $req_dump, FILE_APPEND );
```

Now I have the log file in such format:

```
{"datetime":"2020-04-01 21:39:15","device":"abc","dev_id":"12345","type":"temp123","vers":"123"}
{"datetime":"2020-04-01 21:39:15","device":"abc","dev_id":"12345","type":"temp123","vers":"123"}
...
```

Now I would like to have a show.php for example, to see the data.log content in webpage.
Simply have columns, and content for each line.
Like:

```
datetime             I device I dev_id I type    I vers 
--------------------------------------------------------
2020-04-01 21:39:15  I abc    I 12345  I temp123 I 123
```

Intension is to have show.php file, which creates the colums for table, each column lets say to be 22characters wide, until the last log  item.

Tried with foloowing code, but json parser returns malformed JSON. 
cannot figure out yet what is the reason.

```
<?php

$filename = 'data.log';
$json = file_get_contents($filename);
echo 'Decoding: ' . $string;
json_decode($json);
//var_dump(json_encode($json));
//var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
}
echo PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Any idea, hint, snippet would be appreciated and Thanks.

Comment: `json_decode()` decodes only one JSON block while you have multiple JSONs in `data.log`

Comment: Boris: correct. As afirst step I tried to work with only one line, the response was the same, malformed json.

Answer (score 0):

Each line of your file is a valid JSON string, but the whole file isn't : you need to decode the file line per line :

```
$filename = 'data.log';
$content = file($filename);

foreach($content as $line)
{
    $json = json_decode(trim($line));
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes, i have figured it out that i need to loop through eash line. Your code will help to do so. At the moment I am still confused why do i get malformed json only with one log line. Second stage will be the table...